# "refresh" view on device rotation

Tags: cocoa-touch, rotation, autorotate

I have my view set up in `viewDidLoad`. All the different frames and such of the subviews have been defined relative to `self.view`. Therefore it doesn't matter what size `self.view` is the subviews will always shrink or expand to fit (as it were).

So when I rotate my device I want the view to rotate (easy enough with `shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation:...`) but the subviews stay the same shape.

Calling `[self viewDidLoad];` makes all the elements fit, but puts a new layer on top of the previous layout (which is obvious... but i'm just saying to explain what I mean).

Is there any way to refresh the frames of the subviews or something? I don't know what other people do to be honest. Am I going to have to put ALL of my views into the .h file as properties and do everything manually on `didRotate...`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have three options:

1. If autoresizing masks are good enough to position your views, assign the correct autoresizing mask to each subview when you create them.
2. If autoresizing masks are not sufficient, override `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` and reposition your subviews in that method. I would create a custom method that takes the orientation as a parameter and is responsible for laying out all subviews. You can then call this method from `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` and from `viewDidLoad`.
3. You could also create a custom `UIView` subclass and make your view controller's view an instance of this class. Then override `layoutSubviews` to position all subviews depending on the view's size. This approach implies that your custom view manages its subviews instead of the view controller.

Comment: thanks... looked into autoresizing masks :) that should do for now. :)

Comment: Just to add: If you're writing your own UIView containment controller. You can override `willLayoutSubviews:` and `didLayoutSubviews:` to get notified when the device is rotating.